# Can't format string with a list

Tags: python, string, formatting

I have these two fields

```
s = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %s ORDER BY %s;"
data = ['students', 'age', 12, 'desc']
```

From what I see, I count enough elements in the list to format the string.
But

```
print s.format(data)
#or
print s % tuple(data)
#or
print s % data
```

returns `TypeError: not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: Note that it's usually not a good idea to build SQL statements using string formatting. Instead, pass your data as parameters when you go to `execute` your query. This will allow the DB to escape any special characters which will help you avoid [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Answer (score 2):

Just convert the list to tuple, like this

```
s, l = "SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s = %s ORDER BY %s;",['students','age',12,'desc']
print s % tuple(l)
# SELECT * FROM students WHERE age = 12 ORDER BY desc;
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/A7tG59)

Comment: @Saphire I also included an online demo now. Please check that as well.

Comment: True. I had to restart the interactive python shell. Thanks.